# Playing a sound file when a list item is clicked

Tags: android, listview, media-player

Just a disclaimer, I'm very new to both android and Java.

The end product that I'm going after in this is a soundboard like application.  I want to display a list of sounds that the user can tap on to play the associated sound file.

So far I have setup a couple of string-arrays in my strings.xml file.  One array represents the sounds available, and the second array represents the actual R.raw.soundfile resources.  Might be easier to just show it.

```
<string-array name="alex_list">
    <item>Sound Title</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="alex_sounds">
    <item>R.raw.soundfile</item>
</string-array>
```

Here is the class definition I have so far.  I really don't want anyone to "do the work for me" as it were, but I'm completely lost as to where to progress from here.  I feel like I should pass the string-array position from alex_list (when clicked) to get the right resource from alex_sounds (which should play immediately, doesn't need media controls).  But that's where I get stuck.

```
public class AlexList extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.alex_list, R.layout.list_item));

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            // I have zero clue what to do from here
        }

    });

}
}
```

If there is a better way to do any of this, please tell me.  The last thing I want to do is develop bad habits at an early stage.  I'll continue to work on it and post back if I find a solution.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your values array this way:

```
<string-array name="alex_sounds">
    <item>soundfile</item>
</string-array>
```

Then your listener becomes: (packageName is a string representing the package of your R file: e.g. `"com.example.main"`)

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    String selectedFromList = getItemAtPosition(pos);
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(selectedFromList, "raw", packageName);
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(AlexList.this, resId);  
    mp.start();
}
```

This will play the file which name you selected in your list view, from your `res/raw` folder.
(Coded quickly in StackOverflow, there may be syntax errors)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  How would I go about dynamically inserting the resource id based on which list item was clicked.  So for the MediaPlayer.create(AlexLIst.this, <sound resource that corresponds to list here>);  Also, is there a better way to go about this other than using two string-arrays?

Comment: Okay, now we're getting somewhere!  I can get it to work as long as the item in the alex_list matches the mp3 filename in the res/raw folder.  If I wanted the displayed text to be different and still have this work, how would I go about this?  For example, the display text in the list might say "Welcome to paradise", yet the file is located at R.raw.paradise.mp3.  Thanks for your help, I'm glad I found this site.

Comment: Thank you @Guillaume.  I got the knowledge from your responses that I was looking for.