# stream music from urls onclick items of Listview

Tags: android

I have a custom ListView. There are cardviews in my listview on each of which i want to stream music from internet. I have 3 links for streaming music for three different cardviews. My question is:

- How can i set three different datasources?
- Should i use Adapterview?if yes, then how can i change urls onselecteditem?

I am trying to understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356113/how-to-launch-specific-url-associated-with-listview) .But still can't get what i want.

Comment: Try the approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879993/playing-a-sound-file-when-a-list-item-is-clicked)

Comment: Where can I save my URLS?

Comment: You can store URLs in an `ArrayList`, and get the correct URL in `onItemClick()` by its position.